# PrimeNG Tree Component Disable Element Count

Tags: angular, user-interface, primeng

Can't disable tree element count in p-tree component, it's on by default. Also haven't found any suggestive property in documentation that you could toggle it with, maybe I'm missing something...

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt4Oz.png)

I don't want for it to show 2, 3, 1 how many children the parent has..

Comment: please share some code, atleast html or a stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think you are using older version of primeng.
Try this:

```
<p-tree [value]="files">
    <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
        {{ node.label }}
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v16-lts/tree#template